# MongoDB - $maxscan option

Tags: mongodb

```
C:\>mongo

C:\>C:\Programs\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell!
[test] 2014-02-26 17:09:35.933 >>> db.people.count();
9
[test] 2014-02-26 17:09:39.10 >>> db.people.find({})._addSpecial("$maxscan", 5);
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e61be188483458f1edca7"),
        "name" : "joe",
        "random" : 0.7170755963306874
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e61c2188483458f1edca8"),
        "name" : "mark",
        "random" : 0.6132313262205571
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e61c7188483458f1edca9"),
        "name" : "john",
        "random" : 0.07292630313895643
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e621c188483458f1edcaa"),
        "name" : "allen",
        "random" : 0.09901093109510839
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e636f188483458f1edcab"),
        "name" : "kevin",
        "random" : 0.9719919066410512
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e6375188483458f1edcac"),
        "name" : "nicola",
        "random" : 0.4626409418415278
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e6428188483458f1edcad"),
        "name" : "peter",
        "random" : 0.8568310006521642
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e642d188483458f1edcae"),
        "name" : "tim",
        "random" : 0.5209994465112686
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("530e6437188483458f1edcaf"),
        "name" : "joseph",
        "random" : 0.6217151982709765
}
[test] 2014-02-26 17:09:51.76 >>>
```

I have 9 documents in this collection.
I am calling the `find` query above with
the option `_addSpecial("$maxscan", 5)`.

And still, 9 documents are returned.
I was expecting 5 documents returned.
Why is it behaving this way?

I looked at the documentation here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/

but I don't think it provides any clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is **type-sensitive** and **case-sensitive**, that means that you have to write the operator exactly as it is. You wrote like `$maxscan` but actually, according with the documentation is `$maxScan`.

Comment: Thanks, so it's just a typo in this book I am reading. It is all lower-case there.